# Android - UX design conventions concerning “Cancel” and “Done” buttons

Tags: android, guidelines, standards

How should I display "Cancel" and "Done" buttons in an Android app, or should I even display a "Cancel" button in the first place since the hardware back button (or the action bar's up-navigation) should suffice?

The screenshot below shows how it is done in the Contacts app ...
[image: Cancel and Done buttons in the Contacts app]

... but I am wondering if this is "the way to go", because this way the buttons take a lot of screen space for no reason. On iPhone you have a small "Done" button on the top right (inside the navigation bar / action bar). I prefer to do the same for this Android app, but I don't want to do anything that users don't expect.

So, any advice for me to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use what the stock Contacts app uses...

[image: Screenshot]

It makes sense to demote the cancel option as I'd be worried about accidental taps. An issue with your current design is that a single errant finger during typing could scuttle the Activity.